# How to get value from async function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, async-await

I am trying to get values from my local database, but all I can get is 'Promise{<Pending>}'. Here is my code that I found on the internet. The code below should return a result object that contains table rows, but I am only getting promise.

```
const getFromDB = async() =>{
    return  await pool.query('SELECT * FROM services');
};
```

Comment: How dou you call `getFromDB()`?

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48626761/node-js-mysql-pool-connection-with-async-await ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `async` function always returns a promise.  The resolved value of that promise is whatever value the code in your function returns.  So, to get the value out of that promise, you use either `await` or `.then()`;

```
getFromDB().then(val => {
    // got value here
    console.log(val);
}).catch(e => {
    // error
    console.log(e);
});
```

There is no free lunch in Javascript.  A value obtained asynchronously can only be returned from a function asynchronously (via callback or promise or other similar async mechanism).

Or, if the caller itself was an async function, then you could use `await`:

```
 async function someOtherFunc() {
     try {
         let val = await getFromDb();
         console.log(val);
     } catch(e) {
        // error
        console.log(e);
     }
 }
```