# Go to the next instruction until the function is finished (Node Js)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a code in Node js, which connects to a mysql database and inserts data, however, I have a problem, sometimes as it goes so fast, skips the steps, I would like it to just quit its function when it finishes to insert, do not go to the next instruction until you finish. Then I leave my code.

```
con.getConnection(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Conectado!");
});
function insertarpost()
{
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  var sql = "INSERT INTO `wp_posts` ( `post_author`, `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`, `post_content`, `post_title`,`post_excerpt`, `post_status`, `comment_status`, `ping_status`,`post_password`, `post_name`,`to_ping`,`pinged`, `post_modified`, `post_modified_gmt`,`post_content_filtered`,`post_parent`, `guid`,`menu_order`, `post_type`, `post_mime_type`,`comment_count`) VALUES (1, '"+fhoy+"', '"+fhoy+"', ' ', '"+titulocomilla+"','', 'publish', 'open', 'closed','','"+zlug+"','','', '"+fhoy+"', '"+fhoy+"','', '"+co+"','','0', 'oposiciones','' ,0);";
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    resolve(result);
    console.log("1 registro insertado");
  });
});
}

setTimeout(insertarpost, 1500);
setTimeout(obtenerultimopostid, 1500);

function obtenerultimopostid() {
  con.query("SELECT ID FROM wp_posts ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0,1;", function (err, result, fields) {

    var sql = "INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES ("+result[0].ID+",'nº_plazas', '"+nplazascomilla+"'),("+result[0].ID+",'observaciones', '"+observacionescomilla+"'), ("+result[0].ID+",'descargar_documento_oficial', '"+linkdescarga+"'), ("+result[0].ID+",'plazo_de_instancias', '"+plazasincomilla+"'), ("+result[0].ID+",'ambito', '"+categoriacomilla+"'), ("+result[0].ID+",'tipo', '"+tipocomilla+"'), ("+result[0].ID+",'origen', '"+origencomilla+"'),("+result[0].ID+",'grupo', '"+grupocomilla+"'), ("+result[0].ID+",'fecha_de_publicacion', '"+fpublicacion+"'),  ("+result[0].ID+",'convocante', '"+convocantecomilla+"');";
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    //if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 registro wpmeta insertado");
  });

 var sql = "INSERT INTO wp_term_relationships (`object_id`, `term_taxonomy_id`, `term_order`) VALUES ("+result[0].ID+", '"+co+"', '0');";
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    //if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 registro de categoria insertado");
  });
});
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48626761/node-js-mysql-pool-connection-with-async-await

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your Problem correctly you want to invoke the `obtenerultimopostid` function when the function `insertarpost` has been finished.

If it's the case you can use the Promise Object which you are returning from the `insertarpost` function:

```
insertarpost().then(obtenerultimopostid())
```